# How do i convert code to retrieve data from Firebase V8 to Firebase V9 in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

im having trouble because i have to translate from Firebase V8 to V9 code in my Next.js project. And this is the V8 code :

```
const chatRefs = db.collection("chats").doc(context.query.id);
const message = await chatRefs.collection("messages").order("timestamp", "asc").get();
```

I try to translate to V9 code and it looks like this

```
const ref = doc(collection(db, "chats"), context.query.id);

const messageRes = await getDocs(
    query(
      ref,
      collection(db, "messages"),
      where("timestamp", ">", 0),
      orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
    )
  );
```

And i'm getting an error because of `ref` in messageRes variable. The error is :

```
TypeError: constraint._apply is not a function
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you gone through [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) which describes how to upgrade from version 8 to version 9?

Answer (score 0):

You need a collection reference in your query. To query documents from messages sub collection, try changing the ref to:

```
const ref = collection(db, "chats", context.query.id, "messages");

const messageRes = await getDocs(
    query(
      ref,
      where("timestamp", ">", 0),
      orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
    )
  );
```

Comment: I use this code, but there is a new error like this `FirebaseError: Expected type 'DocumentReference', but it was: a custom CollectionReference object`

Comment: @MMuqiitFaturrahman can you update your question with latest code you have? Also make sure you are using getDocs and not getDoc

Comment: My latest code is this `const ref = collection(db, "chats", context.query.id, "messages");

  const messageRes = await getDocs(query(ref, orderBy("timestamp", "asc")));`